# Can't find element by xpath with title as a variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

selenium can't locate the element, Time Out Exception.
    name="karam"

This works.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="karam"]'))
)
```

This won't work.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@title=str(name)]'))
)
```

nor this.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="{}".format(name)))
)
```

Comment: If you have working code, why ask?

Comment: I want to do it using 'for loop' for different values of 'name'

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your code samples (and check if they still don't work afterwards).

Comment: @SahilDhiman , it's not about missing `0` in curly braces, but you just forgot to close your predicate as well as your XPath, so just add `]'` -> `'//*[@title="{}"]'.format(name)`. P.S. *`'//*[@title="karam"'` This works*... I don't really think so

Comment: Oops,  forgot to put that( I didn't copy but wrote again over here), editing  again, thanks for telling,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
name="karam"
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="{0}"]'.format(name)))
```